# React snap scroll not functioning

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to get the snap scroll feature working in my react app. I've tried using the normal CSS method, but it does not work in chrome as mentioned in [scroll-snap skips section on smaller screen - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66116588/scroll-snap-skips-section-on-smaller-screen-chrome).

So I decided to use the package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-scroll-snap. But the snap scroll feature is not working at all. (When scroll, no "snapping" occurs as expected)

**Expected behavior:
When scroll downwards, the view should snap to the "FIRST" `div` then to the "SECOND" `div` and so on.**

What am I doing wrong here - am I missing something really basic?

Thanks.

App.jsx

```
import useScrollSnap from 'react-use-scroll-snap';
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Topbar from "./components/topbar/Topbar";
import "./app.scss";

function App() {
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
  useScrollSnap({ ref: scrollRef, duration: 100, delay: 50 });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Topbar></Topbar>
      <div className="sections" ref={scrollRef}>
        <div>FIRST
        </div>
        <div>SECOND
        </div>
        <div>THIRD
        </div>
        <div>FOURTH
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

app.scss

```
.App{
    height: 100vh;

    .sections{
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - 70px);
        background-color: lightblue;
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;

        > *{
            width: 100vw;
            height: calc(100vh - 70px);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem. The package https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-snap gave the result that I was looking for.

It works with chrome but not with firefox; I think has to be some minor issue because the package's docs say it supports all modern browsers.

Comment: I am trying to use this package too, but how do I get it worked on firefox?